# prevent div from clipping image with minus margin

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a profile card and I want to display the circle image at the top of it and slightly outside

when I give it a minus margin it clips the top of the image off,

This is what I am trying to achieve

[image: This is what I want to achive]

But this is what I am getting

[image]
is there a way with a tailwind to tell it to overflow? [Demo Codepen](https://jsfiddle.net/b3z5dx96/2/)

```
<div class="font-sans leading-tight min-h-screen bg-grey-lighter p-8">
  <div class="max-w-sm mx-auto bg-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-lg">

    <div class="border-b px-4 pb-6">
        <div class="text-center sm:text-left sm:flex mb-4">
            <img class="h-32 w-32 rounded-full border-4 border-white -mt-16 mr-4" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/21.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="py-2">
                <h3 class="font-bold text-2xl mb-1">Cait Genevieve</h3>
                <div class="inline-flex text-grey-dark sm:flex items-center">
                    <svg class="h-5 w-5 text-grey mr-1" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M5.64 16.36a9 9 0 1 1 12.72 0l-5.65 5.66a1 1 0 0 1-1.42 0l-5.65-5.66zm11.31-1.41a7 7 0 1 0-9.9 0L12 19.9l4.95-4.95zM12 14a4 4 0 1 1 0-8 4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm0-2a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"/></svg>
                    New York, NY
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
            <button class="flex-1 rounded-full bg-blue text-white antialiased font-bold hover:bg-blue-dark px-4 py-2 mr-2">Follow</button>
            <button class="flex-1 rounded-full border-2 border-grey font-semibold text-black px-4 py-2">Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="px-4 py-4">
        <div class="flex items-center text-grey-darker mb-4">
            <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-grey mr-1" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M12 12a5 5 0 1 1 0-10 5 5 0 0 1 0 10zm0-2a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm9 11a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a3 3 0 0 0-3-3H8a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v2a1 1 0 0 1-2 0v-2a5 5 0 0 1 5-5h8a5 5 0 0 1 5 5v2z"/></svg>
            <span><strong class="text-black">12</strong> Followers you know</span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="flex flex-row-reverse justify-end mr-2">
              <img class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-10 w-10" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/32.jpg" alt="">
              <img class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-10 w-10 -mr-2" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/31.jpg" alt="">
              <img class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-10 w-10 -mr-2" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/33.jpg" alt="">
              <img class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-10 w-10 -mr-2" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/32.jpg" alt="">
              <img class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-10 w-10 -mr-2" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/44.jpg" alt="">
              <img class="border-2 border-white rounded-full h-10 w-10 -mr-2" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/42.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
              <span class="flex items-center justify-center text-sm text-grey-darker font-semibold border-2 border-grey-light rounded-full h-10 w-10">+3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the class `overflow-hidden` from the second `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The card element you have has a class of `overflow-hidden` on it. If you remove that then you should be able to see the full image. If you can't change that class for whatever reason then just add the property `overflow:visible` to the card element and you should be good to go.